# Setting my file path to reference a OneDrive directory in VBA Script

Tags: excel, onedrive, vba

I am trying to automate the sending of commission sheets for our admin.  When I move the files locally to my C:, the coding works fine, but when I change that to the local path for my OneDrive account, the scripting fails.  Ultimately, I would like this to be able to reference the OneDrive path, no matter who runs the reports.  Here is my scripting:

```
Sub Send_email_fromexcel()
Dim Edress As String
Dim Subject As String
Dim Message As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim outlookapp As Object
Dim myAttachments As Object
Dim path As String
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim Attachment As String
Dim x As Integer

x = 6
y = 2
Z = 3

Do While Sheets("Austin").Cells(x, 1) <> ""

Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outlookmailitem = outlookapp.createitem(0)
Set myAttachments = outlookmailitem.Attachments

path = Sheets("Austin").Range("B2")
Edress = Sheets("Austin").Cells(x, 1)
Subject = Sheets("Austin").Cells(x, 2)
Filename = Sheets("Austin").Cells(x, 3)
Attachment = path + Filename

outlookmailitem.To = Edress
outlookmailitem.cc = ""
outlookmailitem.bcc = ""
outlookmailitem.Subject = Subject
outlookmailitem.body = Sheets("Austin").Cells(Z, 2)

myAttachments.Add (Attachment)
outlookmailitem.display
outlookmailitem.send

lastrow = lastrow + 1
Edress = ""

x = x + 1

Loop

Set outlookapp = Nothing
Set outlookmailitem = Nothing


End Sub
```